# Insert quote in mysql using c#

Tags: c#, mysql

Can anyone help me to insert single quote in mysql using c#. I know how to achieve that, but i don't know the syntax, so far this is my code

```
 if (txtcode.Text.Contains("'") == true)
  {
      txtcode.Text.Replace("'", "\'");
  }
```

but my txtcode doesnt get the value of \, and also i try this code

```
 if (txtcode.Text.Contains("'") == true)
  {
      txtcode.Text.Replace("'", "\\'");
  }
```

still not working.. anyone can guess how to achieve that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to perform *any* string replacements - just use parameterized SQL and it should be fine.

So you *mustn't* do this:

```
// BAD CODE - DO NOT USE
string sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE Person (ID, NAME) VALUES ('" + id 
    + "', '" + txtCode.Text + "')";
```

That is:

- Vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) (and awkward characters like quotes)
- Brittle in the face of conversions (date/time conversions being particularly painful)
- Hard to read, as it mixes the SQL and the data

Instead, you'd use something like:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE Person (ID, NAME) VALUES (@id, @name)";
using (var command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = id;
    command.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCode.Text;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really use a parameterized query, which will handle quotes correctly, as:

```
string s = "Text with this \'quote\'";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO table (Column) VALUES (@quotedString);", connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quotedString", s);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This also prevents SQL injections on the go.

Answer (score -1):

can you try this one:

```
if (txtcode.Text.Contains("'") == true)
  {
      txtcode.Text.Replace("'", @"\\'");
  }
```

Comment: Also protecting quote with that way is not a good idea. You could use Jon Skeet's or Thorsten Dittmas's answer...